# active_admin dashboard, update_attribute overrides the same attribute in each class member

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I need to set just current order's :released as true

```
   section "Recent orders" do
      table_for Order.where(:released => false).all do |t|
        t.column("Status") {|order| status_tag (order.released ? "Done" : "Pending"), (order.released ? :ok : :error) }
        t.column("User"){|order| link_to order.user.username , admin_user_path(order.user)}
        t.column("Created"){|order| order.created_at.to_formatted_s(:short)}
        t.column("Price") {|order| order.total_price}
        t.column("Actions"){|order| button_tag(:type => 'button') do order.update_attribute(:released, true)  end}     
      end
    end
```

After pressing a button all orders in table set :released as true.
What can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know where you saw you could do that. That's evaluated for each order when rendering. Not when the button is pressed.

Anyway, check this page of the docs to understand how you can create different actions like the one you wan't http://activeadmin.info/docs/8-custom-actions.html#member_actions